# How do I disable the generation of an import library?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, import-libraries

I'm creating a COM DLL in Visual Studio. The linker generates an import library for the DLL. I don't need the import library.

Is there any way to tell the linker not to generate it?

Comment: Import library? Export library? Which is it to be?

Comment: Sorry: import library containing the named exports.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nine years later, this may not be useful to the OP, but it may prove useful to others coming by looking for a solution.

LINK.EXE supports the `/NOIMPLIB` option that prevents creation of an import library, even in the presence of a `__declspec(dllexport)` routine in the `DLL` or `EXE` being linked.

Go to Project Properties, open up the `Linker` section.  The very last option is `Command Line`.  Select that, and there's a place at the bottom to add additional options to the linker.  Enter `/NOIMPLIB` in the edit field, save and apply, and it'll prevent the creation of the `.lib` file.

-- Edit --

Unfortunately, while it does prevent creation of the `.lib` file, empirically I've found that the `.exp` file is still created.  I'd file a bug report with MS, but based on past experience with their developer tools team, trying to get something like this fixed will be akin to trying to roll a boulder up hill.

-- Edit -- four years later --

As noted in the comments,  VS 2019 finally has this fixed, so that `/NOIMPLIB` now suppresses the creation of both the `.lib` and `.exp` files.

Comment: `/NOEXP` suppresses the `.exp` for me on Visual Studio 2019, as inspired by [this bug ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/when-using-def-and-noimplib-with-linkexe-it-create/1495047).

Comment: @Krishty It would indeed appear to have been fixed.  "All hail Sisyphus!"

Answer (score -1):

This answer seems to be the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15214141/660440

"Using a .def file containing your exported functions marked with the PRIVATE keyword will tell the linker to skip placing the symbol in your import library."

Comment: Still generates the import library, though.