# Suppress import library creation - Visual C++ linker

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport, import-libraries

Is there, a perhaps undocumented way to prevent linker from creating `IMPLIB` for a DLL or an EXE, despite having `__declspec`(dllexport) directives within the source code?

Specifying no `/IMPLIB` results in `.LIB` created with a default name.

This is important when the declspec directives arrive from 3rd party code which is not under control. This is, for example, the case with `boost::serialization`.  A possible solution would be a way to "undeclare" a DLL export. DEF file also cannot do it (AFAIK), because it can only add to the export list but not remove from it.

Comment: Can't you just delete it if you don't need it? What's the real problem?

Comment: The real problem is the time it takes the linker to make these (developer productivity optimization in a large firm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many 3rd party code does not use `__declspec(dllexport)` directly, but hides it under a macro in order to control it. Typically they want to switch between `dllexport` and `dllimport` depending on where the header file is included (inside the dll implementation or by the user of the dll)

If that is the case in the library you try to include it should not be too difficult to alter this behavior via macro manipulation to meet your exact needs.

For example, `boost::serialization` check the `config.hpp` and see how you can control it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se8y7dcs.aspx), if you supply the `.exp` file when linking, the linker will not create a `.lib` file. To be honest, though, I can't tell if this helps in your case.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to create an empty EXP file to supply it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any way to do this with a linker option, using /implib:"nul" fails miserably when the linker uses it to name the .exp file.  The most practical solution is to remove the files again after a build.  Project + Properties, Build Events, Post-Build event and paste:

```
del $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).lib
del $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).exp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using a .def file containing your exported functions marked with the PRIVATE keyword will tell the linker to skip placing the symbol in your import library.

Refer to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information about MSVC's .def file syntax.

Comment: Still creates the .lib and and .exp files though.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you can use `/NOIMPLIB` and `/NOEXP` in the advanced linker options as per [this bug ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/when-using-def-and-noimplib-with-linkexe-it-create/1495047). Works for me on Visual Studio 2019.